# NVDA not reading < mat-error > on Firefox

Tags: angular-material, accessibility, nvda

That's the thing, NVDA reads the error label correctly on Chrome but not on Firefox

example: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages

here it works (no idea why, i have the same arias): https://codepen[dot]io/aardrian/pen/WNgmGwr

I've tried:

- [attr.aria-errormessage]="my error", in < mat-form-field>, < input> even in < mat-error>
- role="alert"
- aria-live="assertive"
- aria-relevant="all"

Setting the focus on < mat-error> does the job but i doesn't makes sense because breaks navigation between fields

I couldn't find any related issue here or in its github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aria-live` is not being used properly but unfortunately, the [`aria-label` doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) doesn't really address it so it's not uncommon for it to be used improperly.

And "improperly" might be too strong of a word. If you set `aria-live` on a container and then inject new text into it, it **will** be read by all screen readers, including NVDA on Firefox.  However, if you **dynamically add** a container that has `aria-live`, you'll get spotty support among various screen readers and browsers.  The difference is a bit subtle.

See more details in my answer for: [Why the role="status" attribute doesn't work correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75463994/why-the-role-status-attribute-doesnt-work-correctly/75464404#75464404)

Essentially, going from

```html
<div>
</div>
```

to

```html
<div>
  <div aria-live="polite">
    I'm new!
  </div>
</div>
```

will not announce the new content in all browsers or screen readers. That's exactly what <mat-error> is doing.  If you look at the [example](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages) you posted on the angular site,

```html
<mat-error aria-live="polite">You must enter a value</mat-error>
```

is **added** to the page so it will **not** be reliably announced.  This is a bug in angular.

The codepen example you posted **does** work with all the examples that have live regions because

```html
<span id="Msg01" class="msg" aria-live="assertive">
  <span>Field 1 error using assertive live region.</span>
</span>
```

**exists** on the page.  It is not dynamically added. Instead, the error message changes from `visibility: hidden;` to `visibility: visible;` so new content to the live region has been added (or more accurately, unhidden) and is announced. If the codepen example tried to **add** the <span aria-live="assertive">, then it would **not** have worked with NVDA on Firefox.

So to fix your code, you might have to add <mat-error> to your page so that it's there when the page is loaded but the contents of the <mat-error> container can be empty. Then when you inject new text into that container, it will be read.

Comment: Awesome reply, if you want an aria-live, the element (not its contents) has to be already rendered. Thank you