# Accessibility alert for screen readers on delete action in React

Tags: reactjs, onclick, accessibility, roles, screen-readers

I would like to click to announce that the element has been deleted.
Do you have an idea about the role-'alert' function on react ?
I use this but is not fonctional

```
 <button
       onClick={deleteProductWithTracking}
       className='order-summary-item__infos__delete'
       aria-label={`${remove} ${concatStringNoUndef(
       title,
       subtitle,
       size ? productSize : detail,
       )}`}
            >
       <span className='sr-only' role='alert' aria-relevant='all'>
        {ariaAlertRemoveItem}
        </span>
       {remove}
 </button>
```

Can you please help me
Thank you

Comment: You have an alert span **inside** the button? I would not recommend that. I have two pretty long answers regarding live regions, although not specific to react, that might help. [First one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178816/nvda-chrome-reads-anchor-text-inside-a-hidden-div-twice-when-displayed/75189223#75189223) and [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75463994/why-the-role-status-attribute-doesnt-work-correctly/75464404#75464404).

Comment: Have you read any [docs about Live Regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions)? What have you tried? Did you check slugolicious’s answers? Any role inside a `button` will loose its meaning, you need to put the region outside of the button. Have you tried that?