# How can I force a toast to be read by a screen reader when a modal is open

Tags: accessibility, web-frontend

Voiceover / the screen reader isn't reading the toast messages when a modal is open.
For example, if I have a form within a modal to update my details, I click save, and I am shown a toast. The screen reader does alert me when there is no modal open.
How can I ensure the toast is read or if it is not possible why?

This is essentially the html for my toast

```
  <div
    role="alert"
    aria-live="assertive"
    aria-atomic="true"
  >
    <div>
      <header>Alert from the toast!</header>
      <div>An alert message</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Is the alert added inside the dialog? The nature of a modal dialog is to hide everything else from assistive technology.

Comment: Beware that toast messages are most likely out of view especially for users of screen magnifiers, and more in peripheral vision for anybody else on big screens. They might not be the best way to provide form validation feedback, should you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly already answered.  See my two answers:

- [NVDA Chrome reads anchor text inside a hidden div twice when displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178816/nvda-chrome-reads-anchor-text-inside-a-hidden-div-twice-when-displayed/75189223#75189223)
- [Why the role="status" attribute doesn't work correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75463994/why-the-role-status-attribute-doesnt-work-correctly/75464404#75464404)

You may not have posted enough information for us to answer. Is the toast text added to the live region or is it unhidden?  Is the live region itself added or is it unhidden? I address these two issues in my two previous answers.