# ARIA live content update when VoiceOver is focused via a Braille display

Tags: javascript, wai-aria, voiceover, braille

I am attempting to figure out how a time update event that updates the currentTime in the HTML dynamically, can update itself when the Braille display via VoiceOver is focused on that area.

```
.p-2.flex-grow-1.align-self-center{role: "text"}
    %time{datetime: "PT0M0S", data: {video: {container: {target: "currentTime"}}}} 0:00
    %span /
    %time{data: {video: {container: {target: "duration"}}}}
```

The above is the HTML side which receives the information from the JavaScript of the video element.  Using the role of "text" allows the above to render as:

```
0:00 / 0:00
```

on a Braille display as one line, instead of:

```
0:00
/
0:00
```

three lines.

If the Braille display is focused on this content during playback, the currentTime part doesn't update on the display but does visually.  Moving away from the content then back to it shows the content has been updated.

I don't think what I'm looking for is an aria-live attribute though as setting the politeness to "polite" didn't seem to work.

I am testing with Safari on iIOS 16.

Please let me know if you have any ideas how to provide this dynamic content to the Braille user when focused on it.

Comment: Dynamic content should be conveyed through `aria-live`. For screen reader users, it causes the screen reader to announce the new content added to the live region. For Braille users, it's supposed to update the Braille display. What part of aria-live didn't work? You didn't post any code regarding that. Check out my two answers regarding how to use aria-live to make sure you're using it correctly. (Links to two answers posted in next comment because URLs are too long to include in this comment).

Comment: [first aria-live answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178816/nvda-chrome-reads-anchor-text-inside-a-hidden-div-twice-when-displayed/75189223#75189223) and [second aria-live answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75463994/why-the-role-status-attribute-doesnt-work-correctly/75464404#75464404).