# screen reader won't read text hidden on page load but made visible through JS onclick?

Tags: javascript, screen-readers

Very much a beginner, sorry in advance.

Context: I'm working with a WYSIWYG application to program an interactive 360-photography tour, but the app has lots of flexibility for custom JS coding, which I am just dipping my toe into.

Case: Simply put, I have a webpage with a div containing text, which is hidden until a user clicks a button. The button has text on it that's already visible on page load. In testing with a screen reader (VoiceOver on Mac, Chrome), the VO reads the text on the button just fine. However, when the button is clicked, the hidden div's visibility changes from 'hidden' to 'inherit'. The text appears, but the screen reader won't read it or recognize it.

After reading a few other posts here, I tried setting the text div to role = alert, but the screen reader still didn't read it. It does read it if I change the tabindex to 0 and then tab to the text, but my understanding of WCAG guidelines is that the text shouldn't need to be tab-able since it's not interactive.

I'm not familiar enough with how screen readers work to understand why or be able to identify the root problem.

Test project available [here](https://vbf-examples.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/screenreader/index.html)  in case that's helpful. Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try to add aria-live attribute to the hidden div element and set as "polite" Like this <div id="hiddenDiv" aria-live="polite"></div>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`aria-live="polite"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) on the **containing parent** of the element you are unhiding.

```
<div aria-live="polite">
  <div>
    I'm hidden initially until button click
  </div>
</div>
```

I have two other answers that talk about `aria-live` that might be helpful:

- [NVDA Chrome reads anchor text inside a hidden div twice when displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178816/nvda-chrome-reads-anchor-text-inside-a-hidden-div-twice-when-displayed/75189223#75189223)
- [Why the role="status" attribute doesn't work correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75463994/why-the-role-status-attribute-doesnt-work-correctly/75464404#75464404)

Comment: I'll try this and report back, thank you!